# Imagestring rubbish text issue

Tags: php

I try to add text on image:

```
$newImg = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_width, $dst_height);
imagealphablending($newImg, false);
imagecopyresampled($newImg, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dst_width, $dst_height, $width, $height);

imagesavealpha($newImg, true);
    if(!empty($name)){  
    $fontSrc   = './fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf';//support utf8 and unicode
    $font = imageloadfont($fontSrc);
        //Couleur des noms
        $bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImg, 0, 0, 0, 0);     
        $textcolor = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImg, 255, 255, 255, 1);

        //Deplacer les noms
        imagestring($newImg, $font, 0, $dst_height - 17, 'שדגשדג', $textcolor);
    }
```

already tried:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
imagestring($newImg, 500, 0, $dst_height - 17, utf8_encode('שדגשדגש'), $textcolor);
```

The issue is when i put text in hebrew(utf8): `שדגשד` its show the text on the picture like that:

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH9Yd.jpg)

As you can see its type rubbish text,what is proper way to fix it?

Comment: My first guess is that the used font doesn't support unicode.

Comment: tried that too,i will edit now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally after deep research and tons of test i finally made it happen and can now use utf8 chars,**the issue was imagestring canno't work with utf8** and i should have change to imagettftext and load the ttf font that support utf8 support:

```
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
    $fontGD   = './fonts/DejaVuSans';
    imagettftext($newImg, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $fontGD, 'שגשדג');
```

Thats it,now working.